# Simplify only using one definition

Tags: isabelle

The simplifier (simp) in Isabelle/HOL rewrites by using all the lemmas/theorems/definitions/etc in the system. I know that we can delete a definition from the simplifier. For example, like this:

```
by (simp del:less_imp_le_nat)
```

I need to simplify by only using the lemma **set_rec**. How can I delete all the theorems in the simplifier and only add the lemma set_rec?

Something like:

```
by (simp del_all del:set_rec)
```

Comment: You can use `apply(simp only: set_rec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply(simp only: set_rec)`.